# How do I view a saved web page through IE8's Compatibility View?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have saved a web page to my machine and I'm currently viewing it through IE8.  I make some local changes and check how they look like through IE8.  I am following this workflow because I am integrating an iframe hosted by another server.  Whenever I'm accessing a live site, I can see the Compatibility View icon but while reading the local web page, the icon is not present.

With the above conditions and limitations, how can I view my saved web page through IE8's Compatibility View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under **Tools -> Compatibility view Settings** check the box to display all websites in compatibility view:

[image]

You can turn it off whenever you're finished.